# GPS Latitude Hex To Integer/decimal conversion from 2's complement

Tags: c#, .net

I have a GPS device documentation which states that they send the latitude and longitude data, converted from integer with 6 implicit decimal to HEX. If value is negative, then it's represented in 2's complement format.

We can convert the positive values easily, but problem comes when value is negative. Using C# BitConverter.ToInt32, it converts:

```
Longitude: 24-F7-07-E3 -->> 723388387 (wrong, it must be negative), 
Latitude: 04-05-0C-00 -->> 67439416(correct)
```

For checking if it's negative value or not, we are checking if integer value is outside of lat/land range or not. So if longitude is outside of -180 to 180, then it's negative. But how we can convert this 2's complement value as negative longitude?

Edit:
Adding the code used for converting HEX to integer:

```
// This gives strange value
int longitude = BitConverter.ToInt32(array.Skip(43).Take(4).ToArray(), 0);
Console.WriteLine("Logitude for +RSP is {0}", longitude);
int latitude = BitConverter.ToInt32(array.Skip(47).Take(4).ToArray(), 0);
Console.WriteLine("Latitude for +RSP is {0}", latitude);
// Following gives correct value but not the negative one.
int longitudeC = Convert.ToInt32(BitConverter.ToString(array.Skip(43).Take(4).ToArray()).Replace("-",""), 16);
Console.WriteLine("Logitude for +RSP is {0}", longitudeC);
int latitudeC = Convert.ToInt32(BitConverter.ToString(array.Skip(47).Take(4).ToArray()).Replace("-", ""), 16);
Console.WriteLine("Latitude for +RSP is {0}", latitudeC);
```

Comment: Can you show some code with the given input and expected (and actual) output? I do know about 2`'s, but within this context it's hard to pinpoint the issue ;-)

Comment: Hi @Stefan, i have added the code. I used BitConverter.ToSingle, because i used it for another GPS device and it gives -2.492484E+21, 3.314485E-05 for above HEX number, so i know that first one is negative.